# Probability that certain $k$ cells are not empty

Tags: calculus, probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $M$ cells and $N$ identical balls. What is the probability that certain $k$ cells are not empty?

The answer is $\frac{(M-k)^N}{M^N}$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allowed to put the balls into the remaining $M-k$ cells. There are $(M-k)^N$ ways to do this.

Comment: Right right.. I think I had a blackout for couple of minutes. That's an easy one. Anyway, thank you!